# Creating variable from bash command output in makefile

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, gnu-make

Hello I would like to ask how I can create bash variable in makefile.
Below code does work but variable "targets" keeps being empty. How I can actually create "targets" and "current_target" variables in makefile?. Problem is that I have to create this variables from actual bash commands.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
...
MAIN_APPS = 01_prep 02_prep 03_prep 04_prep 05_prep
foo : .check_targets .check_segment 
    @for f in $(MAIN_APPS) ; do \
        targets=$(expr $(last_target) + 1); \
        echo $(targets) + 1; \
        curent_target=$(expr "$(echo $(f) | head -c 2) + 0"); \
        if [ $(targets) = $(current_target)]; then \
            break; \
        else \
            make $(f); \
        fi \
    done
```

output:

```
make foo last_target="02" segm=KI
+ 1
```

What I want to do is to make targets from my makefile which actually starts from 01 to 05 if I pass an argument last_target="05"

Comment: If you want to use `$()` as shell process substitution, you have to escape the $ to make.  eg: `targets=$$(expr ...`

Comment: You seem to confuse `make` variables that can be expanded using `$(variable)` and shell variables that would be expanded as `$variable` or `${variable}`. Note that you have to write `$$` if you want the `$` to be interpreted by the shell and not by `make`.

Comment: yes i was confused using $ $$ but now i know how to use both of them in makefiles thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mix up between make variables and shell variables. And you did not consider that make expands the recipes before passing them to the shell, reason why you frequently need to use `$$` instead of `$`. Or, for command expansion, `...` instead of `$(...)`. You are also using double quotes where you shouldn't (`expr "..."`). Finally, you use `make` in your recipe, which is not a good idea. You should use `$(MAKE)` (see the [*How the MAKE Variable Works* section of the GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKE-Variable) for the details).

Try the following (not tested) maybe:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
...
MAIN_APPS = 01_prep 02_prep 03_prep 04_prep 05_prep
foo : .check_targets .check_segment 
    @for f in $(MAIN_APPS) ; do \
        targets=`expr "$(last_target)" + 1`; \
        echo "$$targets + 1"; \
        tmp=`echo "$$f" | head -c 2`; \
        curent_target=`expr "$$tmp" + 0`; \
        if [ "$$targets" = "$$current_target" ]; then \
            break; \
        else \
            $(MAKE) "$$f"; \
        fi \
    done
```

But I am almost 100% convinced that you are trying to use make as a kind of scripting language instead of as a sophisticated build system. If I understand well you are trying to rebuild only a subset of your `MAIN_APPS` by specifying a last target number. You could probably achieve the same with a much more make-ish style:

```
TARGETS := $(shell printf '%02d_prep\n' $$(seq $(last_target)))

.PHONY: foo
foo: $(TARGETS) .check_targets .check_segment
```

And that's all, no complex recipe for `foo`. Nothing at all (except, of course, the rules to build `.check_targets`, `.check_segment` and all `xx_prep` targets, that you do not show).

Explanation: I used the `$(shell ...)` make function and a small shell script to initialize make variable `TARGETS` with `01_prep 02_prep ...` up to `$(last_target)_prep`. As noted in the comments this shell script does not even require bash and would work with the default make shell (sh). So, if you do not have other good reasons to use bash, get rid of the `SHELL=/bin/bash` line and your Makefile will be a bit more portable.

Then, I declared `foo` as phony because you probably don't have a file named `foo` and, in case you have one, you probably want make to build `foo` anyway.

Finally, I declared `$(TARGETS)`, `.check_targets`, and `.check_segment` as prerequisites of `foo`. If you ask make to build `foo` and any of these prerequisites is out-of-date, make will build it using the rules you declared for it.

This is far more make-ish because it clearly tells make what depends on what instead of hiding it in a recipe. And make needs this to do its job correctly, which consist in comparing last modification dates of files to decide if something must be rebuilt or not. It also has extra benefits like, for instance, exploiting the parallelism of your computer to build several `xx_prep` in parallel if it is possible.

Comment: There is nothing here which depends on Bash, so the `SHELL=` is really uncalled for (or, conversely, you could avoid the fugly brittle `expr` with more robust built-in arithmetic). But a better solution altogether is probably to refactor this to Makefile code to produce the required dependencies as actual dependencies.

Comment: You don't really need Bash for the `for` loop either, though it's convenient; `TARGETS := $(shell printf '%02d_prep\n' $$(seq 1 $(last_target)))`

Comment: @tripleee You are right but as the OP explicitly used bash I guess there is a good reason. Moreover, just like Paul Smith has a rule number 1 that says "_Use GNU make. Don’t hassle with writing portable makefiles, use a portable make instead!_", I have a rule number 1 that says "_Use bash. Don’t hassle with writing portable scripts, use a portable shell instead!_" ;-).

Comment: @tripleee Updated my answer to indicate that bash is not needed and used your solution.

Comment: Somewhat ironically, [`seq` is not portable either](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298199/portable-posix-shell-alternative-to-gnu-seq1) (-:

Comment: You're right, I just checked in IEEE Std 1003.1-2017 and `seq` is not there! Amazing. But `awk` is, so we can `awk -v e="$(last_target)" 'BEGIN {for(i=1;i<=e;i++) printf("%02d_prep\n", i);}'` ;-).